# How can I use HttpRouter with MuxChain?

Tags: go

I'd like to use [httprouter](https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter) with [muxchain](https://github.com/stephens2424/muxchain) while keeping route parameters like `/:user/`.

Take the following example:

```
func log(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
  fmt.Println("some logger")
}

func index(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
  fmt.Fprintf(res, "Hi there, I love %s!", req.URL.Path[1:])
}

func main() {
  logHandler := http.HandlerFunc(log)
  indexHandler := http.HandlerFunc(index)
  chain := muxchain.ChainHandlers(logHandler, indexHandler)
  router := httprouter.New()
  router.Handler("GET", "/:user", chain)
  http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router)
}
```

When I visit `http://localhost:8080/john` I obviously don't have access to `ps httprouter.Params`
That's because httprouter needs to see type `httprouter.Handle` but the function is called with type `http.Handler`.

Is there any way to use both packages together? The HttpRouter GitHub repo says

> The only disadvantage is, that no parameter values can be retrieved when a http.Handler or http.HandlerFunc is used, since there is no efficient way to pass the values with the existing function parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to patch muxchain to accept `httprouter.Handle`, but it's rather simple to create your own chain handler, for example:

```
func chain(funcs ...interface{}) httprouter.Handle {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, p httprouter.Params) {
        for _, h := range funcs {
            switch h := h.(type) {
            case httprouter.Handle:
                h(w, r, p)
            case http.Handler:
                h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
            case func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request):
                h(w, r)
            default:
                panic("wth")
            }

        }
    }
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/VgZtaJ80W6)

Comment: That's pretty sweet! Could I also mix `httprouter.Handle` and `http.Handler` somehow? So that I don't have to use `p httprouter.Params` in every middleware?

Comment: @zemirco I updated the example, probably a little bit slower than using `p` in every handler since it will have to do type switches on every request.

Answer (score 4):

If you strongly want to use that packages, you can try to do something like that:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/context"
    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
    "github.com/stephens2424/muxchain"
    "net/http"
)

func log(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    fmt.Printf("some logger")
}

func index(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    p := context.Get(req, "params").(httprouter.Params)
    fmt.Fprintf(res, "Hi there, I love %s!", p.ByName("user"))
}

func MyContextHandler(h http.Handler) httprouter.Handle {
    return func(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request, p httprouter.Params) {
        context.Set(req, "params", p)
        h.ServeHTTP(res, req)
    }
}

func main() {
    logHandler := http.HandlerFunc(log)
    indexHandler := http.HandlerFunc(index)
    chain := muxchain.ChainHandlers(logHandler, indexHandler)
    router := httprouter.New()
    router.GET("/:user", MyContextHandler(chain))
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router)
}
```

Comment: Cool idea! It adds another wrapper though. What do you use for web apps in Go? Because you said "strongly want to use that packages". That sounds a bit ironic.

Comment: No ironics! English is not my native language, so I can't express correctly. I use Gorilla toolkit

Comment: @zemirco I *think* he means if you really want to use httprouter and chainmux together you'd have to use gorilla context to "bind" them.